# How Many users accounts am i able to create in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How Many user accounts am i able to create in MySQL?
I am not asking the number of concurrent connections, neither the number of connections per user, i am only trying to find aout how many different user accounts is MySQL able to register.

Comment: What is it good to know the answer?

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want more than 4 or 5 !?!?!

Comment: Lots, but if you're making lots, you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, the question rises because i am working on a platform which is easily breakable, ill be placing small servers in houndreds of locations in a kind of distributed system, even thoug whe are implementing many techniques to protect our servers (encrypted linux boxes) i was thinking in providing any single user with its own MySQL account, so i can track all activity through user accounts, we are already tracking the users through our applications, but there are many users who will be able to acces those servers directly from command line mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL stores its user credentials in a database table, so it's limited by whatever obscene number of rows a MySQL table can hold. These are typically limited by disk space rather than any particular hard limit.

Answer (score 1):

User accounts management is implemented by using `mysql.user` table. Moreover you can create account directly by creating appropriate record in this table. So probably I'll be not very far from the truth when I say that number of user accounts is limited by number of records you can put to this table.